# JDBC resource shared between webapps in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jndi, h2

I have such configuration of database in my Tomcat instance (H2):

```
<Resource name="jdbc_ttDS" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
            url="jdbc:h2:***;IFEXISTS=TRUE"
            username="**"
            password="**"
            maxActive="20"
            maxIdle="5"
            maxWait="-1" />
```

I want to have two applications in this instance, which connect through JNDI. H2 by itself is thread-safe, but file is usually locked during Tomcat is running.

Am I be able to have two JNDI connections inside my Tomcat from two different apps? Is is safe, because mainly one of the applications will insert/drop DB, while another mainly select from it. However, both will have concurrent connections to the DB.

If it is impossible or unsafe, is the best idea to run H2 in server mode?

Comment: "but file is usually locked during Tomcat is running" = ?

Comment: @Leo by default H2 creates lock file for database, which prevents extra connection. For instance, by default, you can't run two Tomcats or Tomcat and some other resource using the same database